# Redux/React is not returning the updated state on first dispatch

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am learning redux/react and I am developing a sample application to understand it, for experiment I am trying to update the checkbox checked property using reducer.

My reducer is as follows.

```
const check_box_state = (state = false, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case ActionNames.TOGGLE_CHECKBOX:
        return !state;
    default:
        return state;
}
};
```

then I am using react-redux connect method to pass this reducer to my component via following code.

```
const StateFullSignInPanel = connect(
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {redux_state: state};
},
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        toggle_check_box: (previous_state) => dispatch(toggleCheckbox(previous_state))
    }
}
)(SignInPanel);

export default StateFullSignInPanel;
```

Finally my component is as follows.

```
class SignInPanel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            checkbox_state: this.props.redux_state.generic_reducers.check_box_state
        };
        this.handleRememberMeState = this.handleRememberMeState.bind(this);
        this.handleSignInClick = this.handleSignInClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleRememberMeState() {
        let previous_checkbox_state = this.state.checkbox_state;
        this.props.toggle_check_box(previous_checkbox_state);
        let new_checkbox_state = this.props.redux_state.generic_reducers.check_box_state;
        this.setState({
            checkbox_state: new_checkbox_state
        });
    }

    handleSignInClick() {
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="ui card sign_in_card">
            <div className="ui input input_fields">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email or username"/>
            </div>
            <div className="ui input input_fields">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div className="ui checkbox remember_me_checkbox">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="remember_me"
                    onChange={this.handleRememberMeState}
                    checked={this.state.checkbox_state}
                />
                <label htmlFor="remember_me">Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <div className="sign_in_button">
                <button className="ui green button" onClick={this.handleSignInClick}>
                    Sign in
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default SignInPanel;
```

State of the checkbox start to update successfully and as expected only after the second time I click it, for the first time `setState` gets the default state from the reducer and checkbox remains unchecked. I am also using loggerMiddleware from redux-logger and it shows that the state is successfully updated from false to true after the action dispatch but even after that new state I receive is false. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you maintain an internal state inside `SignInPanel` when you already have a key on the global state for keeping track of the checkbox status?

Comment: I am still learning and figuring things out. I figured as much that I should remove internal state but still It doesn't solve the problem I am facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach (gotten rid off the internal state and now checkbox is controlled using the exising key on redux state):

```
import { toggleCheckbox } from './actions';

class SignInPanel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleRememberMeState = this.handleRememberMeState.bind(this);
        this.handleSignInClick = this.handleSignInClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleRememberMeState() {
        this.props.toggle_check_box(this.props.check_box_state);
    }

    handleSignInClick() {
        // ...
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="ui card sign_in_card">
            <div className="ui input input_fields">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Email or username"/>
            </div>
            <div className="ui input input_fields">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Password"/>
            </div>
            <div className="ui checkbox remember_me_checkbox">
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    id="remember_me"
                    onChange={this.handleRememberMeState}
                    checked={this.props.check_box_state}
                />
                <label htmlFor="remember_me">Remember me</label>
            </div>
            <div className="sign_in_button">
                <button className="ui green button" onClick={this.handleSignInClick}>
                    Sign in
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}

export default connect(
  (state) => ({ check_box_state: redux_state.generic_reducers.check_box_state }),
  { toggle_check_box: toggleCheckbox }
)(SignInPanel);
```

As per ^^this implementation the redux state is now directly `connect`ed to `SignInPanel`. So we won't need the code for `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to create `StateFullSignInPanel`.

Comment: Thanks, after you pointed out I shouldn't mix internal state with global, I removed it to test what happens and it worked.